# How to create "undulating terrain" for playground in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcscene, tin, terrain

How could I create undulating terrain in ArcGIS? I know I could create it by creating a TIN model but first I need to have "input data" - shapefile with Z (height in attribute). Is there any way I can create something you see at the picture below? The shapefile will be used in ArcScene for 3D of course.

[image]

Comment: The easiest thing to do is probably just draw the contours you want as closed polylines with Z values and then create a surface out of them, be it TIN or raster DEM. Alternatively you can create a bunch of points, give them rough z values approximate to what you want, then generate the TIN and modify it as needed. Drawing the contours would be easier in my opinion, but then I have experience/training in doing grading work.

Comment: @ChrisW Yeah thank you. Actually i just tried it with polyline shapefile but it didn't work first because i forgot to mark "coordinates will contain Z value" during creating a shapefile and i just added "height" in attribute table. Then i wasn't able to create TIN, so i tried it again with Z value and yeah it works! I just need to draw the contours first